# Ajax send data with string name

Tags: php, ajax, post, send

I apologise if this was already answered, but I haven't found an answer in 70k+ results..

I want to send data like this:

```
function _post(params) {

    var func = params['func']; // -> 'getUserDetails'

    $.ajax({
              url: "crossroad.php",
              type: "post",
              data: { func : params },
              cash: false,
              complete: function(respond){
                console.log(respond);
              }
          });
}

m = {};
m['func'] = 'getUserDetails';
m['id'] = '123456';
_post(m);
```

But with this code, php gets

```
$_POST['func']
```

I want string that I am sending to be named as params['func'] and in this case I want to receive in php

```
$_POST['getUserDetails']
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: if you want the variable name in PHP to be "getUserDetails", then do `data: { "getUserDetails" : params }`. Odd name for a variable, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create object

```
var requestParams = {};
```

And then setup it property like

```
requestParams[params['func']] = '';// your data to send
//or
requestParams[params['func']] = params['id'];// your data to send
```

And then put into ajax data property

```
 data: requestParams,
```

Comment: is it `cash: false,` or `cache: false,` ?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile what you mean on `cache` property?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `func` is a valid key identifier, so although you are expecting `func` to be substituted for the parameter you passed in, you are actually declaring a property of your data object called `func`.

To get around this issue, create a new object, and pass it in like this:

```
function _post(params) {

var func = params['func']; // -> 'getUserDetails'
var obj = {};
obj[func] = params;

$.ajax({
          url: "crossroad.php",
          type: "post",
          data: obj,
          cash: false,
          complete: function(respond){
            console.log(respond);
          }
      });
}
```

Comment: is it `cash: false,` or `cache: false,` ?

Comment: cash: false it is

Comment: Thank you, both answers are correct, but sir mr. Zhukov was a minute faster so I'm sorry but I had to award his answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
function _post(params) {

var func = params['func']; // -> 'getUserDetails'
var obj = {};
obj[func] = params['id'];

$.ajax({
          url: "crossroad.php",
          type: "post",
          data: obj,
          cash: false,
          complete: function(respond){
            console.log(respond);
          }
      });
}
m = {};
m['func'] = 'getUserDetails';
m['id'] = '123456';
_post(m);
```